# Saving data with json in custom class

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, json.net

I'm still trying to understand this ajax.

I'm trying to save the Patient from js to the database on the serverside, but the code below always result in [alert("error")]

Can someone see the mistake?

MVC action:

```
public JsonResult CreatePatient(string patient)
{
    var jsonPatient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Patient>(patient);

    if (db.Patients.Contains(jsonPatient))
    {
        db.Patients.Remove(jsonPatient);
    }
    db.Patients.Add(jsonPatient);

    return new JsonResult();
}
```

Custom class:

```
public class Patient
{
    [Key]
    public string Cpr { get; set; }         //ID
    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastname;

    //public List<TestReceving> TestHandelings { get; set; }

    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return _firstname; }
        set { _firstname = value; }
    }

    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return _lastname; }
        set { _lastname = value; }
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return obj is Patient ? Cpr == (obj as Patient).Cpr : false;
    }
}
```

js:

```
function savePatient() {
    var Patient = {
        Cpr: $("#cpr").val(),
        Lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
        Firstname: $("#firstname").val()
    };

    var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(Patient);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Patient/CreatePatient",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: dataToPost,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            // do what you want on success.
            alert("saved");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

I have changed it to:

```
public JsonResult CreatePatient(Patient patient)
{
    if (db.Patients.Contains(patient))
    {
        db.Patients.Remove(patient);
    }
    db.Patients.Add(patient);

    return new JsonResult();
}
```

and

```
function savePatient() {
    var Patient = {
        Cpr: $("#cpr").val(),
        Lastname: $("#lastname").val(),
        Firstname: $("#firstname").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Patient/CreatePatient",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: Patient,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            // do what you want on success.
            alert("saved");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

But I am still getting the error.

Comment: public JsonResult CreatePatient(Patient patient)

Comment: Hi. I tried what you said, but still gets the error. Will you take a look again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need to `JSON.stringify`, just send `Patient` as is:

```
data: Patient,
```

and recieve in action:

```
public JsonResult CreatePatient(Patient patient)
{
    ...
}
```

**Update:** while sending raw json (not stringified) `contentType: "application/json"` should not be used.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still get the error. I have edited the question. Will you take a look at it again?

Comment: @user3265569 does your action getting fired? if yes then u have some exception in action, try to debug it

Comment: I am getting: "typeName": "System.ArgumentException", "message": "Invalid JSON primitive: Cpr.",

Comment: @user3265569 try remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Add `[HttpPost]` attribute on the method body like

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult CreatePatient(Patient patient){...}
```

Comment: I'm gonna mark "Gene R"'s as solved I think it was a combination of both thougt. Thansk for your response.